# Multiple values in 1 field PHP

Tags: php

I need to have a form selection with the following process:

1. Open box
   Number of passengers / Type

   ```
               <select style='height:40px;width:45px;font-size:11pt' name=\"code1\" value=\"$code1\" class=\"select\">
               <option value=\"0\">0</option>                      
               <option value=\"1\">1</option>   
               <option value=\"2\">2</option>
               <option value=\"3\">3</option>
               </select>&nbsp;

               <select style='height:40px;width:120px;font-size:11pt' name=\"code1\" value=\"$code40\" class=\"select\">
               <option value=\"Adult(s)\">Adult(s)</option>                    
               <option value=\"Children\">Children (2-11yrs)</option>   
               <option value=\"Infant(s)\">Infant(s) (0-2yrs)</option>
               </select>&nbsp;
   ```

This can be a combination of both. A perfect example is lufthansa.com site, you can see under Traveller and travel class

A passenger family can then select 2 adult(s) / 2 Children / 1 Infant
then goes into the `$code1` field with the final result

I have managed to do a compromise with labels:

Adult(s): 
Children (2-11Yrs): 
Infant(s) (Less than 2Yrs):

This has worked but cannot get all the data ie. 1 adult / 1 child in one field. Trying to upload into $code1 of my form

Comment: What is your question? You've only shown a piece of code and stated you need something like that piece of code. One thing I can immediately tell you, though, is that this is invalid HTML - the `name` attribute should be unique. This way your second `select` value overwrites your first.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I am looking for the code that will open the box from the field and we can then select 1 or 2 or 3 and the category Adult children or infant. Once it is selected it goes into the field in order to upload in my table under $code1.  I put the code I have to maybe joind the two into one boxe selection...

Comment: I'm still not 100% clear on what you're looking to do, but it seems to me that you just have to give these `select`s a different name and then you will have two pieces of data submitted which you can then handle however you want.

Comment: I have found a compromise, and did the following but still cannot have all the date 
<label>Adult(s): <input type='number' name='qty[a]' value='0'></label><br>
<label>Children (2-11Yrs): <input type='number' name='qty[c]' value='0'></label><br>
<label>Infant(s) (Less than 2Yrs): <input type='number' name='qty[i]' value='0'></label><br>